# Add list items to jqueryui through C# code-behind

Tags: c#, jquery, .net, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-selectable

I am using [this plugin](http://jqueryui.com/demos/selectable/) to display a selectable list.

Although it works fine, I need these list items to be populated from code behind C#.
Can you please point me into the right direction?

This is the codebehind section:

```
 wnetEntities1 db = new wnetEntities1();
 var wl = from w in db.wnet_available
         join role in db.wnet_userinfo
         on w.UserID equals role.UserId
         where w.AvailStatus == 1 && role.WLId == 1
         select new { w.UserID, role.FirstName };

wl.ToList();
foreach (var w in wl)
{
    var name = w.FirstName;
```

//guessing this is where the li items should be generated.
    }

And this is the html list (which needs to be generated from asp.net):

```
        <ol id="selectable">

        <li class="ui-widget-content">Item 1</li>
        <li class="ui-widget-content">Item 2</li>
        <li class="ui-widget-content">Item 3</li>
        <li class="ui-widget-content">Item 4</li>
        <li class="ui-widget-content">Item 5</li>
        <li class="ui-widget-content">Item 6</li>
        <li class="ui-widget-content">Item 7</li>
    </ol>
```

Comment: In the code behind, can you not generate a dictionary list and return it to js so that u can populate using ur jquery plugin?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

to be able to see your `ol` element in server side, first add `runat="server"` to it:

```
<ol id="selectable" runat="server">
```

Then you can easily add your `li`s to it:

```
foreach (var w in wl.ToList())
{
    HtmlGenericControl li = new HtmlGenericControl("li");
    li.Attributes.Add("class", "ui-widget-content");
    li.InnerText = w.FirstName;
    selectable.Controls.Add(li);
}
```

Comment: Hi @Kamyar, tried to do the above but I am unable to set the ClientIDMode for the "ol" element. That property does not appear on the intellisense.

Comment: @AmitPhilips This is added in .Net 4

Comment: Hi @kamyar although intellisense doesnt show it, i put it on n it works. thanq so much :)
(using .NET 4.0)

Answer (score 0):

Like this ?

```
   <% var items = wl.ToList(); %>

        <ol id="selectable">

         <%   foreach (var w in items)
            { %>
            <li class="ui-widget-content"><%=w.FirstName %></li>

            <% } %>
       </ol>
```

Comment: pls forgive me for my lack of knowledge. but where should i write the above mentioned code... in the codebehind or the .aspx ?
why are you using "<% %>" is this some technique ?

Comment: No, it's a markup for C# code inside ASP/ASPX page. You can follow Kamyar answer if my answer is not clear or is not good at all for your question

Comment: thank you snake eyes & @kamyar for replying.
i followed the inline asp method which snake eyes mentioned (needed this in my scenario) its working great.

calling the jqueryui with the "runat = server" disabled the list functionality as well as the style :) thankx guys super happy :)

Comment: @Amit: you'd have to set `ClientIdMode` to `static` to force asp.net to use your id and not generating a new id for the `ol` element.

Comment: @Kamyar how do i obtain the selected li itemms on the code behind file ?